# Twitter Equivalent to Facebook Comments?

Tags: api, twitter

My site needs the Twitter equivalent of the Facebook Comments plugin... You may be aware of the fact that Twitter only searches back about a week, so comments would be lost just a few days after being made!  Is there a service that would allow me to show the tweets that contain the given page's unique #hashtag?  I'm looking to put together a system that searches for the hashtag and puts those tweets up for display, even if the tweets are old.  Does anyone know how to make this possible?  I'm not that good of a programmer, FYI...

Comment: I've never seen anything along these lines. [DISQUS](http://disqus.com/) has an option of fetching and storing tweets that reference a post's URL instead of a hashtag that may be close enough for your purposes.

Comment: what do you mean by hashtag? the hashbang at the end of the url on twitter.com? `!#/username` or a hashtag in a tweet?

Comment: Hashtag, as in "I just got my #car washed for free", where #car is the hashtag.  The idea is that a search could be done for all tweets with the page's ID as a hashtag.  In other words - find all tweets with hashtag #hdku83j from the past year or two and then display them nicely... There's gotta be something like that, right?!

Answer (score 0):

No. The Twitter Search API will not let you search that far back.

> The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets. At the moment that index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets.
>
> You cannot use the Search API to find Tweets older than about a week.

From https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search